# Access/rights to Infragistics images and javascript in Sharepoint for a page in _layouts

Tags: sharepoint, infragistics

The Infragistics images and javascript files are located on the server in: "\nasmoss\c$\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\Infragistics".

I created a page and put it in the _layouts folder in Sharepoint. It is just a hierarchical grid. It has the + to expand the group.

For certian users, it displays a red X showing the images are not available. I also get javascript errors since it can't get access to the javascript include files from Infragistics.

If I login with a network admin login, it works. If I login with my normal user account it works sometimes. The fix is to login with my admin account and then login with my noraml account.

This also affects other normal users. If they get the red X I just login with my admin account. It then works for them for a while.

It appears it is some rights issue with Sharepoint. But it is very intermittent. I can't reproduce it. It normally stops working in a day sometimes hours. We don't use that page very often (twice a week).

If I right click and get the full path to the image it is to WebResource.axd.

https://sharepoint.{domain}.com/WebResource.axd?d=I9i-y5iGqdXx3n6e-hSXFEHlcHb2DBAtYdLbT5A8vP6aSSCjd8JdrowGqkDSq5wmAwCgXjgrfYNtCF93yfPliD2yteSxJvg7xIPVnlttFE7Wxg6qGtLaLI18s2hN40PO0&t=633480367580000000

If I have a user put that into their browser, they get an "access denied" error when it is not working. Otherwise they get the + image.

Perhaps it is a caching issue?

Thanks,
Gary Milke

Answer (score 1):

If it's a WebResource.axd it usually means the image is an assembly resource. If the axd somehow gets the images from the filesystem, it might be so that the perrmissions on the folder you mentioned are incorrect. the AD groups WPG_... (i.e. all groups that have capital WPG in their name) and IIS_IUSRS should have read permissions on any file that needs to be accessible in your site.

Especially for files *copied directly* into the 12 hive this might not be the case.